# How to automatically adjust the <textarea> height to the inner text's height using only css without using javascript?

Tags: html, css, text, textarea, height

Is it possible to automatically adjust the  height to the content's height using only css without using javascript?

For Example, When the height of the  is 200px, when the text inside is written only as much as 100px in height, I hope that there will be no blank space.

I want the height of the text inside the  to affect the height of the  itself. There is way to use javascript all over the internet. But I want to implement it using only css and html. I need help!

Here is my code.

```css
.code-wrap {
    margin-top: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #1e1e1e;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.code-title {
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    background: #242E64;
    padding: 21px 24px;
}

.area-wrap {
    padding: 21px 24px;
}

textarea {
    border: 0;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
    font-family: 'D2Coding';
}
```

```html
<div class="code-wrap">
    <div class="code-title"><p>Result</p></div>
    <div class="area-wrap">
       <textarea
            rows="15"
            cols="50"
            name="quiz-editor"
            id="mainResultArea"
            class="ed-result"
            readOnly
          >
          </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: Changed `className` in your HTML to `class` so the snippet looks better.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, there is no great way of doing this using raw CSS or HTML. However, you can stray away from the `textarea` element and use the `contentEditable` attribute on a div or text element.

Check out this basic example & write in this sample text box:

```css
div {
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable></div>
```